# Mostrar un php con javascript

Tags: php, javascript

necesito mostrar o imprimir en pantalla unos banner por medio de javascript.

El listado de los banners a mostrar los llamo así,

```
<?php $zona= "derecha_h1" ;
include("mostrar_ads.php"); ?>
```

Donde, "mostrar_ads.php" es un script que me trae de la DB todos los banners de la posición (variable) "zona".
Como podría hacer esta llamada con javascript, como verán soy muy poco entendido de JS.
Gracias!

**Reformulo o aclaro**:
Con el php funciona perfecto el mostrar los banner en una posición indicada, el problema es que si le hago un caché a la página, no me audita los banner,  Solo muestra datos de la ultima carga antes del cache).

(el "mostrar_ads.php" carga el o los banner de esa  posición, y los contabiliza cada vez que se muestran entre otras funciones )

Supuse que con javascript me traería a mostrar en "tiempo real" por más que tenga un caché, a eso me refiero. Espero se entienda. Gracias!

Comment: Por favor modifica la pregunta y muestra ejemplos de los banners y cómo quieres que se muestren.

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer la llamada con JS, lo que puedes hacer es usar AJAX. Si buscas por ahí veras multitud de ejemplos que te ayudaran a como hacerlo.
Puedes visitar si quieres esta web. https://code.tutsplus.com/es/tutorials/how-to-use-ajax-in-php-and-jquery--cms-32494.

La forma mas o menos de como hacerlo sería con un código similar a este:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#loginform').submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'login.php',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(response)
        {
            var jsonData = JSON.parse(response);

            // user is logged in successfully in the back-end
            // let's redirect
            if (jsonData.success == "1")
            {
                location.href = 'my_profile.php';
            }
            else
            {
                alert('Invalid Credentials!');
            }
       }
   });
 });
```

});

En la parte del $.ajax, es donde llamarías a tu fichero PHP y en data, debería poner la variable que te has declarado

Answer (score 0):

**En tu archivo js:**

```
function mostrarBanners(zona) {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'mostrar_ads.php',
    type: "post",
    data:{
         zona:zona
    },
    success: function(respuesta) {
      $("#cajaBanners").html(respuesta);//div donde mostrar los banners      
    },
    error: function() {
      alert("Zona incorrecta");
    }
  });
}
```

Esta función la puedes mostrar al hacer click a un elemento html, como un botón o bien al cargar el documento mediante `$(document).ready(function() { //aquí la función}`, aunque con esto último deverás definir la variable antes, si nó dara error porque la enviará a **mostrar_ads.php** null y no hará la consulta mysqli correctamente.

**En mostrar_ads.php**

```
$zona = $_POST["zona"];

//haces la consulta
//muestras los resultados con un echo (que es "respuesta" en la función AJAX)

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {  
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "id: " . $row["id"]<br>";
  }
} else {
  echo "0";
}
```

Si quieres mostrar los banners en diferentes posicones, en success puedes hacerlo, asignando el resultado a diferentes div u otros elementos mediante el id.

Espero haberte aclarado un poco las dudas.

Pd: requiere JQuery

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Aclarale que requiere usar JQuery